# git diff branch1..branch2 not working on windows visual studio code

Tags: git, github

I run this diff command at root folder and get this error.
git diff clustering_bb..clustering_bb1

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'clustering_bb..clustering_bb1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: is `clustering_bb` a branch?

Comment: yes it is a branch name

Comment: Can you do git branch -a and show the results? It might be that one of those is on remote and not available locally yet.

Comment: * clustering_bb1 \n
  master \n
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master \n
  remotes/origin/clustering_bb \n 
  remotes/origin/clustering_bb1\n
  remotes/origin/master```

Comment: yes i think clustering_bb is not available locally

Answer (score 2):

From the output of git branch -a it looks like you don't have clustering_bb checked out locally. Git diff is looking for a local branch named clustering_bb so you can either do `git diff origin/clustering_bb..clustering_bb1` or checkout clustering_bb as a local branch and your previous command will work.